# Upper bound for Meijer-G function

Tags: calculus, asymptotics, special-functions, upper-lower-bounds

What I need is a monotonically decreasing function that forms an upper bound for the following function:
\begin{equation}
- G_{0,6}^{4, 0}\biggl({-\atop -\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},\frac{5}{6},\frac{7}{6},\frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{3}}\bigg| x \biggr) \qquad ,x\in\mathbb{R}_+
\end{equation}
where G is the Meijer-G function.

By estimating the asymptotes (calculated by Mathematica) for $x\rightarrow \infty$, I found the following candidate:
\begin{equation}
f(x)=\frac{e^{-3x^{\frac{1}{6}}}\sqrt{\pi}}{96x^{\frac{1}{12}}}\bigl(54+18\sqrt{3}+(96+32\sqrt{3})x^{\frac{1}{6}}\bigr)
\end{equation}

The question is: Is it indeed true that $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}_+ \qquad - G_{0,6}^{4, 0}\biggl({-\atop -\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},\frac{5}{6},\frac{7}{6},\frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{3}}\bigg| x \biggr)\leq f(x)$ ?

And if so, how could I proof it?
If not, are there other ways to find an upper bound?

Maybe one can prove this if one would have an full asymptotic series expansion of the Meijer-G function for $x\rightarrow \infty$. But I do not know how to calculate this.

Comment: $G(1/x)$ is easily obtainable (see inversion formula) so you can work with the series $x \to 0$ of that

Comment: The Mathematica syntax for this Meijer-G function is: -MeijerG[{{}, {}}, {{-1/2, 1/2, 5/6, 7/6}, {1/3, 2/3}}, x]

Comment: Thanks ! By the way, when you answer a specific user write *@username* in your comment. Cheers :-)

Comment: As @G.Cab commented, let $x=\frac 1y$ and expand as series around $y=0$ (using the assumption $y>0$). No problem with Mathematica.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Thank you very much. The problem is that Mathematica calculates only finitely many terms of the series. I think for the proof I need a formula for all terms of the series. This I would have to calculate somehow by hand.

Comment: Where is coming the monster from ? Knowing it could help.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici The monster arises when you calculate the 3-dimensional generalized Fouriertransform of $\sqrt{1+||x||_2^6}$. Since the function is radial symmetric you can calculate it through the hankel transform. The mathematica syntax is: `(HankelTransform[Sqrt[1 + t^6]*t^(-1 + 3/2), t, s, 1/2, 
    Assumptions -> s > 0]*Sqrt[2])/(s/2)^(1/2)`. To obtain the above expression, the inversion formula is once used with $x=\frac{s^6}{46656}$.

Comment: Please ! Don't say *this* monster; instead say *the* monster (as I wrote). Cheers & thanks for the information. By the way, I am still trying.

Comment: Sorry, I edited my comment and thank you for your efforts.